# How do I insert commas into text?

Tags: csv, vbscript

I have to insert commas at certain points in lines of text, using VBScript. I need it to check the first four charcters of each line with an if statement and if it matches it inserts the commas required for that line this is what I have so far:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("H:\Letter Display\Letters\LTRPRT__00000008720000000001NI-K-RMND.txt", ForReading)

strNIK = "1000"
strLine = objFile.ReadLine

If Left(strLine,4) = strNIK then

  arrCommas = Array(16,31,46,56,66,79,94,99)

  Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream

    intLength = Len(strLine)
    For Each strComma in arrCommas
      strLine = Left(strLine, strComma - 1) + "," + Mid(strLine, strComma, intLength)
    Next
    strText = strText & strLine & vbCrLf
  Loop

end if

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("H:\Letter Display\Letters\LTRPRT__00000008720000000001NI-K-RMND.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.Write strText
objFile.Close
```

If anyone could help with making this an IF statement it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `ReadLine` and the conditional inside the `Do..Loop`:

```
strNIK = "1000"
arrCommas = Array(16,31,46,56,66,79,94,99)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = objFile.ReadLine

  If Left(strLine, 4) = strNIK then
    intLength = Len(strLine)
    For Each strComma in arrCommas
      strLine = Left(strLine, strComma - 1) + "," _
        + Mid(strLine, strComma, intLength)
    Next
  End If

  strText = strText & strLine & vbCrLf
Loop
```

If you want the output to consist only of the modified lines, move the line `strText = strText & strLine & vbCrLf` inside the conditional:

```
If Left(strLine, 4) = strNIK then
  '...
  strText = strText & strLine & vbCrLf
End If
```

Do the comma indexes in your array already account for the positional shift that is caused by the character insertion?

Also, it might be a good idea to write the output line by line to a temporary file and then replace the input file with that temporary file after you finished processing all input:

```
Set inFile  = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inputFilename, ForReading)
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(outputFilename, ForWriting)

Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = inFile.ReadLine
  'do stuff with strLine
  outFile.WritLine
Loop

inFile.Close
outFile.Close

objFSO.DeleteFile inputFilename, True
objFSO.MoveFile outputFilename, inputFilename
```

That way you can avoid memory exhaustion when processing large files.

You can process all files with a specific extension in a given directory like this:

```
folderName = "C:\some\folder"

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(folderName).Files
  If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "ltr" Then
    'processing takes place here
  End If
Next
```

If you want to use the inputfile/outputfile approach I suggested above, you can either use the same temporary outputfile name for each input file, or you can derive the outputfile name from the inputfile name, e.g. like this:

```
inputFilename  = objFile.Name
outputFilename = inputFilename & ".tmp"
```

Comment: Thanks alot, would you be able to show me how to do it for every file in a directory all with the same extension .LTR?