# Modify VBS – Excel Macro Loop Apply to all files in folder

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have a script that applies a macro to multiple excel spreadsheets. The code below opens specific file names and runs the script. I would love to modify this to run on all xls files within a specified folder. Any help would be great!

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook, xlModule, strCode

If ReportFileStatus("C:\Billing\Import\IL\3.xls") = "True" Then
    OpenFile "C:\Billing\Import\IL\3.xls, ""

If ReportFileStatus("C:\Billing\Import\IL\3.xls") = "True" Then
    OpenFile "C:\Billing\Import\IL\3.xls", ""   

If ReportFileStatus("C:\Billing\Import\IL\3.xls") = "True" Then
    OpenFile "C:\Billing\Import\IL\3.xls", ""   

End If


On Error Resume Next
Set xlModule = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

'~~> Sub to open the file
Sub OpenFile(sFile, DestFile)
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    objExcel.Visible = false
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFile)
    Set xlModule = objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

    strCode = _
"Sub MACRO()" & vbCr & _

'~~> My Macro Here

"End Sub"

    xlModule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode



    objExcel.Run "MACRO"

    objWorkbook.Close (False) '<~~ Change false to true in case you want to save changes
    objExcel.Application.Quit
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if file exists
Function ReportFileStatus(filespec)
    Dim fso, msg

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
        msg = "True"
    Else
        msg = "False"
    End If

   ReportFileStatus = msg
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: open google.com   type in vbscript loop through files.  you get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665748/vbscript-to-loop-through-all-files-in-a-folder     a whole 5 seconds to complete

Comment: I'd prefer http://stackoverflow.com/a/4201069/603855

Comment: Unfortunately my knowledge with programming in general is rather limited. I will look this material over and see if I can incorporate it into what I have. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is pretty simple, given a folder path, process all files in it (or only certain files based on extension), and all files within it's subfolder. The simplest method is **recursive subs and functions with some global variables** in a single thread.

The next thing to consider is to **Import** .bas file instead of trying to add text to a new module. You need to export a working code from a Module first.

Below assumed the root folder to be "**C:\Billing\Import**", the exported module .bas file is "**C:\Test\Module1.bas**", and the Sub name you want to execute is "**MACRO**".

```
Const sRootFolder = "C:\Billing\Import"
Const sExportedModule = "C:\Test\Module1.bas"
Const sMacroName = "MACRO"

Dim oFSO, oFDR, oFile ' File and Folder variables
Dim oExcel, oWB ' Excel variables (Application and Workbook)

Start    
'------------------------------
Sub Start()
    Initialize
    ProcessFilesInFolder sRootFolder
    Finish
End Sub
'------------------------------
Sub ProcessFilesInFolder(sFolder)
    ' Process the files in this folder
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).Files
        If IsExcelFile(oFile) Then ProcessExcelFile oFile.Path
    Next
    ' Recurse all sub-folders from this folder
    For Each oFDR In oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder).SubFolders
        ProcessFilesInFolder oFDR.Path
    Next
End Sub
'------------------------------
Sub Initialize()
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End Sub
'------------------------------
Sub Finish()
    oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub
'------------------------------
Function IsExcelFile(oFile)
    IsExcelFile = (InStr(1, oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile), "xls", vbTextCompare) > 0) And (Left(oFile.Name, 1) <> "~")
End Function
'------------------------------
Sub ProcessExcelFile(sFileName)
    On Error Resume Next
    wscript.echo "Processing file: " & sFileName ' Comment this unless using cscript in command prompt
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sFileName)
    oWB.VBProject.VBComponents.Import sExportedModule
    oExcel.Run sMacroName
    oWB.Close
    Set oWB = Nothing
End Sub
'------------------------------
```

Feel free to ask if you get stuck understanding the program flow.

Comment: The only issue I'm having is the Macro doesn't run. The module gets saved into the sheet but never runs. I see the oExcel.Run sMacroName therefore I find it odd that it doesn't. I'm fairly sure I didn't typo anything. I'll have to keep working on it. Thank you for your help!